# How to read Volumesnapshot object (or any K8s object)

Tags: go, kubernetes

I want to read & parse Volumesnapshot object (or any K8s object) in go. I tried  to take reference from https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go .

I am trying to add custom annotations in VolumeSnapshot CRD metadata as

```
apiVersion: snapshot.storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: VolumeSnapshot
metadata:
  name: new-snapshot-test
  **annotation:**
        **test:Tushar**
spec:
  volumeSnapshotClassName: csi-hostpath-snapclass
  source:
    persistentVolumeClaimName: pvc-test
```

I also have a custom CSI driver. I need my CSI driver to look for that volumneSnapshot in K8s api server and parse this custom annotation and then process accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow any of the examples in the Github repo [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples). For example using the dynamic/unstructured way (code snippet based on [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/dynamic-create-update-delete-deployment/main.go)):

```golang
func main() {
    var kubeconfig *string
    if home := homedir.HomeDir(); home != "" {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", filepath.Join(home, ".kube", "config"), "(optional) absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    } else {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", "", "absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    }
    flag.Parse()

    namespace := "default"

    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", *kubeconfig)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    client, err := dynamic.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    volumesnapshotRes := schema.GroupVersionResource{Group: "snapshot.storage.k8s.io", Version: "v1beta1", Resource: "volumesnapshots"}

    // List VolumeSnapshots
    prompt()
    fmt.Printf("Listing volume snapshots in namespace %q:\n", apiv1.NamespaceDefault)
    list, err := client.Resource(volumesnapshotRes).Namespace(namespace).List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, d := range list.Items {
    ...
        // do whatever with the items (print, etc)
    }
    // Finish up
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Rico for your response. I have few queries that I need to clarify it with you. 
1. Instead of getting config object from kubeconfig, can we use context or createSnapshotRequest to create the config object? 

2. When user applies VolumeSnapshot yaml file then K8s creates a volumesnapshot object internally. I need to access that object at runtime and process it acccordingly before the actual volumeSnapshot is taken. By creating config object and using that to get volumesnapshotRes and then eventually list all the volumeSnapshots corresponding to namespace, will it be a right approach?

Comment: 1. you can use the context if it's already preconfigured with variables. createSnapshotRequest sounds like it's mean to create a snapshot. 2. that sounds like the right approach

Comment: could you please let me know how can I parse different annotations / attributes using "d" in  for _, d := range list.Items {}

Comment: `metadata, found, err := unstructured.NestedInt64(d.Object, "spec", "metadata")` ? Will that work?

Comment: I did try metadata, found, err := unstructured.NestedInt64(d.Object, "spec", "metadata") but the issue is I get compile time error as d.Object undefined (type "github.com/kubernetes-csi/external-snapshotter/v2/pkg/apis/volumesnapshot/v1beta1".VolumeSnapshot has no field or method Object) Please suggest